# Linux, symlinked Dir, Meld and git

Tags: linux, git, symlink, meld

I'm having trouble bringing meld to work with a git-repo in a symlinked folder.

Let's assume I have the following folder structure:

```
/home/thorsten/a/b/c/git_repo/d
```

then I also have a symlink to the git_repo folder in my home dir as follows:

```
fast -> a/b/c/git_repo/d
```

so

```
/home/thorsten/a/b/c/git_repo/d
/home/thorsten/fast
```

point to the same folder...

Now comes the problem

I'm running the following command in both folders

```
meld .
```

so this will run just fine: (and show diff of current state of repo to last checked in stuff)

```
/home/thorsten/a/b/c/git_repo/d meld .
```

this will not (displays all files as unversioned)

```
/home/thorsten/fast meld .
```

So I'm not sure where so start looking.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the Solution:

The problem was that the symlink was actually pointing at a subfolder of git_repo. But because the "real" parent folder is not visible from inside the symlinked dir, meld cannot see the .git folder.

Maybe this will help someone having the same problem in future ;)